# Open Source CMS based on kohanaphp

Tags: open-source, content-management-system, kohana

Im searching open source CMS based on kohana.
I want to see ideas used in admin section and all idea for cms. 
Please show me smth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluehawk was working on [Kohanut](http://kohanut.com), but last I read, he's been busy and hasn't updated it in a couple of months.  I've also seen one called [S7N CMS](http://code.google.com/p/s7ncms/) in the past but don't know as much about it.

Answer (score 2):

[Gleez CMS](https://github.com/gleez/cms) seems to be active these days. I haven't tried it much though, but in testing it looks good. Or there's [BDQCustom](http://www.bdqcustom.com/) (about which I know less).